# Java EE Server Independent Security

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, jboss, websphere

I am currently in the process of writing a web app (a collection of RESTful web services) that has the potential to be deployed on multiple different application servers (`JBoss` and `WebSphere` are two different containers we want to support out of the box initially).

Whenever I look online for security examples for `JBoss`, they reference **JBoss specific authentication/authorization classes**, which obviously wouldn't work on WebSphere.

Is there a good way (either a `Java EE` standard or a 3rd party framework) to handle security in a container independent manner?

I was originally planning on having the container handle authentication then authentication would be handled with custom code on each of the REST methods.  However, after setting up basic authentication in my `web.xml`, **JBoss** seems to be doing some sort authorization on its own and gives me a **403** after a successful log in.  In WebSphere, I am able to define an "All Authenticated" role that will authorize all authenticated users, but I am not sure how to do the equivalent in JBoss (and in a container independent method).

Here is my web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>identify-service-web</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>All resources</web-resource-name>
            <description>Protects all resources</description>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>ApplicationRealm</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>ApplicationRealm</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>
</web-app>
```

I am a Java EE security newbie, so please excuse the fact that I might have missed something extremely obvious.  Hope someone can push me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the `security-constraint` in the `web.xml` you define authorization for the applicaiton. So your configuration means: *Only authenticated users with the assigned role ApplicationRealm have access to this application.*

You can use a role-mapping in security-domain in the JBoss AS7.1 / EAP 6.x / WildFly. For instance use CLI commands:

```
/subsystem=security/security-domain=other/mapping=classic:add
/subsystem=security/security-domain=other/mapping=classic/mapping-module=mapRoleToAllUsers:add(code="org.jboss.security.mapping.providers.role.DatabaseRolesMappingProvider", type="role", module-options=[("dsJndiName"=>"java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS"), ("rolesQuery"=>"SELECT 'ApplicationRealm' FROM Dual WHERE ?!=''")])
reload
```

which result in following configuration in the `standalone.xml`:

```xml
<security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
        </login-module>
        <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
    <mapping>
        <mapping-module name="mapRoleToAllUsers" code="org.jboss.security.mapping.providers.role.DatabaseRolesMappingProvider" type="role">
            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS"/>
            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT 'ApplicationRealm' FROM Dual WHERE ?!=''"/>
        </mapping-module>
    </mapping>
</security-domain>
```

Then all authenticated users get the `ApllicationRealm` role automatically.

I strongly recommend to use `jboss-web.xml` to define security domain for your application, even if the default one is used:

```xml
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>other</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

There is currently [an issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1105809), which causes the roles are not mapped correctly when the `jboss-web.xml` is omitted.

Comment: Very informative, thank you kwart!  Can it be assumed that most (or all) app servers will use the `<security-constraint>` field in the web.xml in order to authenticate users into the application?  Should you then be able to define the type of authentication (LDAP, Kerberos, RDMS, etc) and authorization (all authenticated are authorized) from configuration values within the app server?  We are planning on providing our customers with a precompiled WAR/EAR that they deploy on their app server that should just require server configuration changes (no changes to the WAR are needed).

Comment: Yes, all app-servers (and servlet containers like Tomcat, Jetty, ...) must force authentication and authorization when the `<security-constraint>` together with `<login-config>` is used. This is a part of Servlet specification, which the servers must follow.

Comment: Then it depends on the app-server configuration, from where the user population is loaded and how role mapping is processed.

The standard deployment descriptor `web.xml` usually covers most of the needs. But for advanced configuration may be necessary to add a vendor specific deployment descriptor (e.g. `jboss-web.xml`, weblogic.xml)

Answer (score 1):

Just as kwart wrote, security settings defined in web.xml or by standard security annotations must be implemented by all containers, so its safe and portable to use them.

What is server specific, is how user to security role mapping is defined, what can be a user registry (e.g. ldap, file, database, custom), and additional authentication mechanisms supported by contaier (e.g. Kerberos, SAML, custom).

For general information on Java EE security, you can check Securing a Web application chapter in [WebSphere Application Server V7.0 Security Guide](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247660.htm) (although saying about Java EE 5, most information is still valid in the latest release).

For example how to configure web.xml for  JAX-RS application in WebSphere check [this page](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=matt&product=was-base-dist&topic=twbs_jaxrs_impl_securejaxrs_webcont):

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use spring-security as an common authentication mechanism... But in general mixing spring and Java EE is not a good idea.

You can use the standard Java EE security framework, if you  want to deploy your application in some containers you will need to provide specific configuration for each container, this shouldn't be a problem because that configurations will not be too long and each container should ignore the specific configuration of other containers.

If you jboss gives you a 403 error even in a sucessful login sounds like a misconfiguration. Have you checked the security domain in WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml?
In jboss if you doesn't define any auth-constraint in the security-constraint it will accept any user.

Comment: I don't actually have a jboss-web.xml defined in my WAR.  I was hoping that the default behavior of it would be to authorize any authenticated user, but that wasn't the case.  Maybe I just need to drop a base jboss-web.xml in my WAR?  I was avoiding that because it is app server specific, but you're right when you say that the other containers will just ignore it...